# Deploying Meteor: Error: spawn ENOENT at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to deploy a Meteor Application on Ubuntu 12.04.3 x64 [following this tutorial](http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/deploy-meteorjs-vhosts-ubuntu1204-mongodb-apache-proxy).

MongoDB and Nginx seems to be correctly set up.

```
# on my Mac
meteor bundle app.tar.gz
sudo scp -r app.tar.gz user@server.com:/srv/data_studio/web/

# on my VPN
tar -xvzf app.tar.gz; rm app.tar.gz
cd bundle
rm -r programs/server/node_modules/fibers
npm install fibers@1.0.1

export MONGO_URL='mongodb://user:password@host:port/databasename'
export PORT=58080
export ROOT_URL='http://localhost/'

node main.js
```

And the following error occurs:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

The same thing appears with forever main.js.

Note that when I'm running sudo node main.js, I get:

```
Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo-livedata/remote_collection_driver.js:41)
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750)
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: `sudo` runs with its own environment. So to be able to pass `MONGO_URL` variable to the `main.js`, you need to preserve the environment with `sudo -E`. You shouldn't need `sudo` unless you are trying to run `Meteor` on a port < 1024. Since the tutorial suggests using Apache, you probably are not doing that with Meteor. And I am assuming that you replaced the `username`, `password`, `port`, `databasename`, etc. placeholder text with the actual values before execution?

Comment: Thank you for the sudo explanations. I'm not using Apache but Nginx. Yes I have replaced it with my db values. I have even reinstalled Mongo, same error.

Comment: And I'm running Node v0.10.26 on both my mac and my VPN so I assume that it is not a node version relative problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from one of my file which was using the spooky node module to crawl ressources on the web. I just forgot to install phantom and casper on my VPN.